# MALFORMED_ID error on detail page button

Tags: apex, javascript, webservices, button

I have a detail page button on Opportunity record . I am trying to call a Webservice class method and do some operation. I am trying to pass the Id as parameter.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/18.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/18.0/apex.js")}
var ID = '{!Opportunity.Id}';
alert(ID);
var newurl=sforce.apex.execute('refreshOpp','refreshOpps',{oppId:"{!Opportunity.Id}"});
```

But i get the alert of ID being proper.
But throws error like shown in screen shot[image].

Comment: Adding "" dint work .:( But I got the solution . I am passing ID only instead of "{!Opportunity.ID}". It called the required method. But i am not sure WHY it says MALFORMED_ID Initialy for {!Opportunity.ID}